# DB reset after deploy to meteor servers

Tags: database, meteor, deployment

I re-deployed my app to meteor by using '*meteor deploy* ' 
and my Database was reset.
Any clue why this happened or how I can avoid it in the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a meteor app is deployed, your data saved in local mongo would not deployed to the server. So you could use mongodump and mongorestore to solve it:([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/))

Now first dump your database somewhere

```
mongodump --host localhost:3001
```

Get your mongodb`s credentials by running (in your app dir):

```
meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com --url
```

This will give you database url in the form:

**mongodb://`username`:`password`@`host`:`port`/`databasename`**

With these info you could fill them into `mongorestore` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore)) and restore your local database over

```
mongorestore -u username -p password -h host:port -d databasename ~/desktop/location_of_your_mongodb_dump
```

All of your data would get transferred in this way. I wish it could help.

Comment: I don't need my local db, I wanted the db that was on meteor servers to remain there and it was "reset" to empty one